# Printing .pem key DER form in python

Tags: python, rsa, private-key, pycrypto, m2crypto

I would like to print out the binary form (not sure if this is how I would refer to it) of a .pem key using python. To clarify, I want to do in python what this unix command would print out:

```
cat privateKey.pem | openssl rsa -pubout -outform DER
```

I can't just call this command using subprocess because I want it to work on Windows. I've looked at the M2Crypto and PyCrypto libraries, and with the M2Crypto library I am able to load the key using

```
from M2Crypto import RSA
rsaKey = RSA.load_key('privateKey.pem')
```

But I don't see any methods of rsaKey that print out the binary form.

Edit:

Here's what I have so far:

```
import M2Crypto
key = M2Crypto.RSA.load_key('key.pem')
bio = M2Crypto.BIO.MemoryBuffer()

key.save_key_der_bio(bio)

der = bio.read()
```

But `der` isn't the same as what openssl printed out. I piped the output of openssl into hexdump to compare them.

Comment: Is your key encrypted? (You can check by opening the file in a text editor)

Comment: It's not. It looks like -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----SOME BASE 64 ENCODED TEXT-----END PRIVATE KEY-----

Comment: Have you tried [`save_key_der`](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2crypto/api/M2Crypto.RSA.RSA-class.html#save_key_der)?

Comment: Yeah, that does the same thing as save_key_der_bio, but to a file. The contents of that file are the same as when I save to a bio and read that bio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

key = RSA.importKey(open("privatekey.pem").read())
der = key.publickey().exportKey("DER")
```

Comment: Wow, much simpler than my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. So the unix command

```
cat privateKey.pem | openssl rsa -pubout -outform DER
```

Is actually printing out the DER form of the public key.
Here is what I had to do, using the M2Crypto library:

```
import M2Crypto
privatekey = M2Crypto.RSA.load_key('privatekey.pem')

bio = M2Crypto.BIO.MemoryBuffer()
privatekey.save_pub_key_bio(bio)

pubkey = bio.read()
pubkey = ''.join(pubkey.split('\n')[1:-2]) # remove -----BEGIN PUB KEY... lines and concatenate
der = base64.b64decode(pubkey)
```

This is the form that I wanted. For some reason, if I did

```
pubkey = M2Crypto.RSA.load_pub_key_bio(bio)
pubkey.save_key_der_bio(bio)
der = bio.read()
```

It gave me the wrong answer.